# Swift : how to add separators to a String at not fixed intervals only when matching conditions?

Tags: swift, string, formatting

So I have this portion of code :

```
stringName = "\(param1)\(param2)\(param3)\(param4)\(param5)"
```

All these params are calculated inside the function in which the stringName is being called.
What I wanna do is output the string name with all these params separated by say a coma, which in theory would be just as easy as separating them by a coma inside the string, however I want the coma to appear only between these params when they exist and they won't all exist in every case.
Because the function I'm creating depends on an array and these params on the array length, so in some cases the returned string will be :

```
stringName = "param1,param4"
```

or

```
stringName = "param2,param3,param5"
```

etc...
(got a maximum of 8 of these params)
So as sometimes these params end up being empty strings, I don't wanna end up with a string name only made of comas, just want my comas to appear inbetween 2 params when they're not empty strings.
Any idea how to format that ??

Thanks !

Comment: If you start with an array of strings you can simply use the `joined` method: `["1", "2", "3"].filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: ",")`

Comment: We can provide a more useful answer if you show how you get the `param1` to `param8` variables. You could potentially use an array to represent them.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked !

@Sweeper : the functions to calculate all params are quite complex, not sure it would be of much help if I had posted these intricate if conditions but anyway the other guys' answer perfectly worked and outputted what I wanted, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `param1`,...,`param5` are all `String`, non-Optional, you can write something like this:

```
let param1: String = ""
let param2: String = "value2"
let param3: String = "value3"
let param4: String = ""
let param5: String = "value5"

let stringName = [param1, param2, param3, param4, param5]
    .filter {!$0.isEmpty}
    .joined(separator: ",")
print(stringName) //->value2,value3,value5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put all your `paramX`s in an array, filter out the empty ones, and used `joined(separator:)` to join them:

```
stringName = [param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7, param8]
                .filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: ",")
```

An even better way of doing this would be not use 8 different variables, and rewrite your method so that it uses an array from the very beginning.

Comment: thanks a lot that perfectly worked !
Yes these params were variables from the very beginning of the code, that could be modified afterwards in a function, but I didn't know how filter & joined tricks, I need to learn more about those ;)